# Update installed iOS App with build which is signed with a new provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

We have an iOS app installed on several devices which is signed with a wildcard provisioning profile.

Now I want to update the app with a new version. The new version is now signed with an app specific provisioning profile.

Both provisioning profiles have the same `team-identifier`, thus the same distribution certificate, which is `WK4KGBC588`.

But the update wont work. The iPad throws the following error:

> Upgrade's application-identifier entitlement string (WK4KGBC588.BundleIdentifier) does not match installed application's application-identifier string (EA8HUU2E2K.BundleIdentifier); rejecting upgrade.

As seen, the `team-identifier` is prepended to the `bundle-identifier` of the app, but only on the app which is signed with the app specific profile. The already installed app has a different identifier prepended. I investigated the .ipa and discovered that this is the `keychain-access-group`. Strange, since I don't use keychain in my app. However, since these two values differ, iOS won't update my app.

So my question, how can I update the live app with the newly signed build?
Deleting the already installed app version is not an option.

Comment: team id is different use same team

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use same team ID, Check this solution from Apple's doc

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2319/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013778-CH1-ERRORMESSAGES-UPGRADE_S_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER_DOES_NOT_MATCH_THE_INSTALLED_APP)